# sql datetime to compare with string

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc-3

if i have the following to access an sql database for a date to compare it to a string that a user enters:

```
public IQueryable<Audit> FindAllAuditsByNameDate(String name, String date)
        {
            return from audit in db.Audits
                   where audit.EventTime.ToString().Contains(date) && audit.User.UserName.Contains(name)
                   orderby audit.User.UserName
                   select audit;
        }
```

it fails is the user enters the "/" character in a date. how do i work around this?

Comment: Have you tried converting the date String to a DateTime type before comparing?

Comment: How about parsing the string to datetime and comparing then?

Comment: You can do something like this also -- EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(audit.EventTime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `DateTime.Parse`. It's able to understand a lot of the common formats for entering DateTimes.

```
DateTime dateStart = DateTime.Parse(date);
DateTime dateEnd = dateStart.AddDays(1);

return from audit in db.Audits
       where audit.EventTime >= dateStart &&
             audit.EventTime < dateEnd &&
             audit.User.UserName.Contains(name)
       orderby audit.User.UserName
       select audit;
```

If `DateTime.Parse` doesn't parse the format you want, you can always use `DateTime.ParseExact` and provide your own format strings.

Answer (score 2):

Considering EventTime is of type DateTime? you need to check it against its value. First convert the string date to DateTime

```
DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
return from audit in db.Audits
                   where audit.EventTime.Value == newDate && audit.User.UserName.Contains(name)
                   orderby audit.User.UserName
                   select audit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning - Don't use `Contains`.

### Disadvantages of Contains

Suppose I have two list objects.

```
List 1      List 2
  1           12
  2            7
  3            8
  4           98
  5            9
  6           10
  7            6
```

#### Using Contains, it will search for each List-1 item in List-2 that means iteration will happen 49 times !!!

---

### Answer to your original Question

```
public IQueryable<Audit> FindAllAuditsByNameDate(String name, String date)
{
    DateTime Dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out Dt))
    {
        return from audit in db.Audits
                where audit.EventTime.ToString().Contains(date) && audit.User.UserName.Contains(name)
                orderby audit.User.UserName
                select audit;
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

### TryParse

> 1. Returns a bool indicating whether it succeeded.
> 2. It just try/catch internally that why is implemented without exceptions so that it is fast.
> 3. Use it in case the value may be InValid.

### Parse

> 1. Throws an exception.
> 2. Use it if you are sure the value will be valid